# What does SI Register point to in string processing instructions?

Tags: arrays, string, assembly

In an example of **buffer scanning** in Jeff Duntemann Assembly Language book it is given that beginning address of buffer is placed in EBP & the no of characters is placed in ECX.

```
mov ecx, esi ;Places the number of bytes read into ECX
```

Does **Source Index(SI)** register point to the address of **last character** being read in a string or to the size of string?

Comment: That's impossible to say without the rest of the code, so by shortening your question like this, you limited it to be answerable only by people who have the book available. But if you have the example working in computer, stepping over it in debugger by single instruction and checking all values in registers and memory will very likely explain things faster and more accurately, than any text answer here on web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will point to the **next character** to be read.

If the `DF` flag is clear (post-increment mode) `ESI` will point to the last character read plus 1.

So if the last character read is located at address `0x1234` then `ESI` will contain `0x1235`.

If the first character is located at address `0` and the data being read is `N` characters long then the last character read is located at address `N-1` and `ESI` will contain the value `N`...